# Products of permutations $(xy)z(xy)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Dealing with the computational examples I understand how to do it. However, I am trying to find the "trick" of finding $(xy)z(xy)$ where $z$ is a permutation. In the examples I solved $(12)z(12)$ when I was given $z$ , however, I'm unsure of how to show this for all $(xy)z(xy)$.

Essentially, I want to find a conjecture, then prove it for all $(xy)z(xy)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: examine what conjugating a cycle by a transposition does; then decompose $z$ into a product of disjoint cycles and you will be set

Comment: I have not ever heard of "conjugating a cycle". Is this another term for something else? I just tried to find out what it means online, but I'm not understanding what it means.